# Paring an Image to a Textblock

Tags: html, css

```css
.Spotify:hover img { display:block;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 0;
     top:17%;
     left: 14%;
     width: 45%;
    height: auto;
 }
```

```html
<a class="Spotify" href="Spotify" rel="history"><img src="https://files.cargocollective.com/c160628/MS_Spotify.png">Spotify</a>
```

When you hover over the text blocks on my homepage a selected case study image appears. Every word/image has a unique piece of code. Which all works fine until you resize the website or look at the mobile version and the images and words aren't aligning anymore. Is there is a piece of code that I can make this responsive? So the image stays with the selected text block at all time. (preferably the image stays underneath the word right aligned)

My website: [www.maartjesmolders.com](http://www.maartjesmolders.com)

Answer (score 1):

Run the below snippet, in fullscreen, then switch into mobile mode.

Basically, I am giving the image full width in mobile mode through media query query

```css
.Spotify:hover img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 17%;
  left: 14%;
  width: 45%;
  height: auto;
}

img{
display:none;
}

@media(max-width:768px){/*You can change this to any number lesser than this*/
 
 a{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  
 }
.Spotify:hover img{
  top:120px; /*height of the text on your website*/
  left:auto;
  right:auto;
  bottom:auto;
  width:100%;
  height:auto
 }

}
```

```html
<a class="Spotify" href="Spotify" rel="history">
  <img src="https://files.cargocollective.com/c160628/MS_Spotify.png"/>Spotify
 </a>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your help! It seems to work for Spotify. But then I tried to use the same code for the text block "Ninety" and the picture doesn't align with the text when resizing the browser. The text box gets broken up when over a few lines when going to the mobile version. But the image stays in the same place. You can see it > www.maartjesmolders.com

Comment: @MaartjeSmolders give position:relative to all anchor tags